# Scion of the Ur-Dragon and Leyline of the Void

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

Does [Leyline of the Void](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Leyline%20of%20the%20Void) prevent the [Scion of the Ur-Dragon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Scion%20of%20the%20Ur-Dragon)'s transformation by exiling the dragons?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Even with Leyline of the Void in play, Scion of the Ur-Dragon's ability still works.

The relevant part of the ability is

> Search your library for a Dragon permanent card and put it into your graveyard. If you do...

This is actually a cost, as defined in [rule 117.12](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/index.php?title=Cost):

> Some spells, activated abilities, and triggered abilities read, **“[Do something]. If [a player] [does or doesn’t], [effect].”** or “[A player] may [do something]. If [that player] [does or doesn’t], [effect].” The action [do something] is a cost, paid when the spell or ability resolves. The **“If [a player] [does or doesn’t]” clause checks whether the player chose to pay an optional cost or started to pay a mandatory cost, regardless of what events actually occurred.**

As you can see, the last part of the rule says that the effect happens as long as you *choose* to pay the cost, even if the outcome is different. In this case, as long as you find a Dragon permanent card and choose to put it in your graveyard, even if it doesn't actually end up in the graveyard, Scion of the Ur-Dragon still becomes a copy of it.

Comment: Wow I would have gotten this one wrong. Is there another rule that makes it clear that you can still refer to "that card" in order to copy it? In Dominion rules for example, "that card" would be interpreted as "the card you put it your graveyard", which wouldn't exist in this case.

Comment: @GendoIkari **400.7g** "A resolving spell or activated ability can perform actions on an object that moved from one zone to another while that spell was being cast or that ability was being activated, if that object moved to a public zone." It doesn't specify that the card has to be in the zone where the effect intended to put it.

Comment: @GendoIkari The first ruling on Scion's page also specifies that it doesn't matter whether the dragon is still in the graveyard for the purposes of Scion's ability.

Comment: Since the ruling mentions "removing", it is probably talking about the other card leaving the graveyard *after* the Scion's ability resolves.